# Dax function for same period last year is not working in excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, data-modeling

So I have a data model that I am using for analysis in excel power pivot. One of the tasks is to calculate YTD sales amount. Now for that task I can use combination of CALCULATE, SUM and SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR functions. Only problem is that this is not working when using Power Pivot in Excel but is it working when I am using Power BI. I imported my data model in PBI and tested the same function.

When working in excel measure created with SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR reports an error for contiguous dates but it doesn't happen in PBI.

Does anyone know why is this happening? The problem is that I have to use excel so that is why I am asking this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR on a Date Column from a non-date table? In that case it won't work because Time Intelligence functions such as SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR require a complete date column as the argument, so I would suggest you create a date table from your Fact table or by creating a custom function in Power Query.

Here is a link for creating a robust date table: https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/extended-date-table-power-query-m-function/6390

And then use SPLY like this:

```
Something =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Sales],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( Dates[Date] )
)
```

Comment: I am using separate Date table, as I should. As I said this works in Power Bi but for some reason i doesn't in Excel. In the meantime I discovered that the problem is that I have Year in columns and months in rows. When I move Year in rows function works. But in Power BI the everything works fine.

Comment: @MilosAcimovic Show the code that you have created with SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR, contiguous error as the name suggest appear when you are using a date column that doesn't have full set of dates.